# Validation error for website

Tags: html, forms, validation

I'm having some strange validation errors for my website. I've gone through my html multiple times but I just can't seem to find the culprit. You can view the w3 validation here;

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftubebackgrounds.co.uk%2Funi%2Fassignment1%2Faustria.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&outline=1&group=1&No200=1&verbose=1&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
li {
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Stylesheets.js"> </script>
<title>CTEC1801: Austria Fact Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_austria.css" title="Style_One" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_austria2.css" title="Style_Two" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_austria3.css" title="Style_Three"/>  


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        var name = ".stylechange";
        var menuYloc = null;

                $(document).ready(function(){
                        menuYloc = parseInt($(name).css("top").substring(0,$(name).css("top").indexOf("px")))
                        $(window).scroll(function () { 
                                offset = menuYloc+$(document).scrollTop()+"px";
                                $(name).animate({top:offset},{duration:500,queue:false});
                        });
                }); 
//]]>
</script>
</head>


<body>


<div id="wrapper">   
<div class="stylechange"> 
Choose a style:

<a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyle('Style_One')">- Style One</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyle('Style_Two')">- Style Two</a>
<a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyle('Style_Three')">- Style Three</a>

</div>  

  <div id="nav">
    <a href="explanation.html" class="home">Explanation Page</a> 
    <a href="#" class="austria">Austria</a> 
    <a href="#" class="switzerland">Switzerland</a>
    </div><br />

    <div id="logo"> <a href="http://www.roamintl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/austria.jpg"><img src="images/austrian_logo.jpg" alt="Austrian Logo" width="940" height="350" /></a></div>

<div id="content-left">

    <h1 id="top">Random facts of the day!</h1>

    <h2>Capital of Austria</h2>
     <ul>   
        <li>Veanna</li> 
    </ul>           
    <h2>Total Area of Austria</h2>

    <ul>
        <li>Total: 83,870 sq km</li>   
        <li>Land: 82,444 sq km </li>   
        <li>Water: 1,426 sq km  </li>   
   </ul> 

    <h2>Population of Austria</h2>
    <ul>   
        <li>8,419,000 million and counting </li>
   </ul>     
    <h2>Languages of Austria</h2>
    <ul>    
        <li>German (official nationwide) </li> 
        <li>Slovene (official in Carinthia) </li>
        <li> Croatian (official in Burgenland </li>
        <li> Hungarian (official in Burgenland) </li>
    </ul>   
    <h2>Life Expectancy in Austria</h2>
    <ul>     
        <li>Total population: 78.92 years </li> 
        <li>Male: 76.03 years </li>
        <li>Female: 81.96 years (2005 est.) </li>
     </ul> 
    <h2 class="right">history and Heritage</h2>
    <ul class="right">     
        <li>The Austrian flag is one of the oldest in the world </li> 
        <li>They hold the worlds largest emerald </li>
        <li>The sewing machine was invented here </li>
     </ul> <br /><br />
    <h2 class="right">Land and Nature</h2>
    <ul class="right">     
        <li>62% of Austria is covered by the Alps </li> 
        <li>Holds the tallest waterfall in Europe </li>
        <li>One fourth of the population of Austria lives in the Capital </li>
     </ul> 
    <h2 class="right">Business and Economy</h2>
    <ul class="right">     
        <li>Austria has the second lowest unemployement rate </li> 
        <li>Among Europeans, Austrians work the longest with the average of 45 hours a week </li>
        <li>Over 60% of Austria's electricity is supplied by a renewable source </li>
     </ul> 
 </div>

<div id="contact">

        <h1>Contact us</h1>

<div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">  

    <h2>Please fill in the details below as needed.</h2>  

    <form method="post" action="http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html6ed/examples/forms/showform.php">  

        <div class="form_name">* Name:</div>        
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""/>  

        <div class="form_name">* Email Address:</div>      
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" />  

        <div class="form_name">* Message:</div> 
        <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>  

        <div class="form_required">* indicates a required field </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" />  
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset-button" />   
    </form>  
</div>  




</div>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The w3 validator tells you exactly where the errors are...

Comment: If you wrap a <div> around those inputs, your validation errors should go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XHTML 1.0 Strict, the form tag cannot contain input and textarea elements as direct children. To be valid XHTML, the input tag must be wrapped by another block-level element, such as `<p>` or `<fieldset>`. Is there any reason you can't use XHTML transitional or HTML5 docyptes?

For more info on XHTML strict and the form element, see http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/form/

Comment: It is for an assignment, I have to use XHTML Strict otherwise I will loose a lot of marks. Thanks for the information, I should be able to get it sorted!